# Does the fluid bake while rendering?

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation, baking

I have a scene in which I have multiple domains with fluids. Is the fluid simulation calculated automatically while rendering even if it hasn't been baked before? If so, can I disable this when I want to render scene only with one baked domain in order to get a faster result?

Comment: No, it's not calculated automatically. But if the _Cache Type_ is set to _Replay_ and the animation was played in the viewport or jumped to any frames, there is most likely data in the cache which gets rendered, though the animation might not be accurate or even get crazy (therefore better bake before rendering). If you've set the type to _Modular_ or _All_ and haven't baked it, there will be nothing rendered. So to avoid having certain simulations rendered you preferably won't use _Replay_ and with other types make sure the cache is cleared. Or disable render visibility for those domains.